# NEXT SENTENCE and nested sentences

Tags: cobol

I have come across this bit of code and am wondering which line will be executed if x is smaller than 3.

```
IF (X < 3)
    NEXT SENTENCE
ELSE
    GO TO A010-DO-A.

GO TO B010-DO-B.
GO TO C010-DO-C.
```

I am not sure if the NEXT SENTENCE will notice the sentence nested in the ELSE block. When NEXT SENTENCE is executed will it skip over GO TO A010-DO-A. or GO TO B010-DO-B.?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'nested sentence' in COBOL, and therefore no 'nested sentence in the ELSE block' here either. It is a nested *statement.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse the scope of statements and sentences in COBOL.

Sentences end with a period (or full stop if you are British). Next Sentence
goes to the next statement following the end of the current Sentence. In
your example that would be `GO TO B010-DO-B`

In general usage of `NEXT SENTENCE` in Cobol is depreciated - at least since
the introduction of scope terminators such as `END-whatever` (eg. `END-IF`)
which happend sometime around 1985! Please do not
use `NEXT SENTENCE` any more. You need to know what it is and what it does
in order to read legacy code, but please
avoid using it in any new code.

A better way to write the code in your example would be:

```
IF (X < 3) 
    CONTINUE  
ELSE  
    GO TO A010-DO-A 
END-IF    

GO TO B010-DO-B  
GO TO C010-DO-C
```

or...

```
IF (X >= 3) 
    GO TO A010-DO-A 
END-IF    

GO TO B010-DO-B  
GO TO C010-DO-C
```

Notice all the periods (`.`) have been removed because
the scope terminator `END-IF` makes them redundant. Periods
are only needed at the end of procedures (ie. paragraphs/sections) and a few other places.
The `CONTINUE` statement is basically a no-op so has no affect other than being
a place holder to keep the syntax valid.

BTW... Best I can tell, the statement `GO TO C010-DO-C` is logically unreachable.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm simply reading this legacy code which I have to convert to a PL/SQL Procedure (I tried to rewrite here to make it generic). Some of it is very confusing and I see why NEXT SENTENCE has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If X is less than 3

```
IF (X < 3)
    NEXT SENTENCE
```

Otherwise, or in other words, if X is equal to or grater than 3

```
ELSE
GO TO A010-DO-A.
```

Comment: yes but will the NEXT SENTENCE statement skip over to GO TO B010-DO-B. or GO TO C010-DO-C.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation, what I was getting at is what @NeilB said, as he points out this will go to GO TO B010-DO-B. because  GO TO B010-DO-C. is logically unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

NEXT SENTENCE "branches" (a GO TO in whatever language is generated by the compiler) to the line of code following the next full-stop/period that is located physically after the NEXT SENTENCE statement. It is effectively a GO TO without needing a "label".

As has been said, it should not be used in new code.